# Template hierarchy constructor arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm having trouble understanding why my template hierarchy won't pass constructor arguments deeper than one layer.

So far I've read that it may have something to do with namespacing or template constructors being unnamed. My various attempts at getting the constructor arguments through to the base class with scoping directives have failed.

```
// test.cc
#include <string>

// Base class, obviously.
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Base(const T& t) : _t(t) {}
    virtual ~Base() { }

    virtual T getVal() const { return _t; }

private:
    T _t;
};

// First derivation. This works, although it is explicit.
class DerivedOne : public virtual Base<std::string>
{
public:
    DerivedOne(const std::string& path) : Base<std::string>(path) {}
    virtual ~DerivedOne() {}
};

// Second derivation. Constructor fails to compile unless I explicitly
// pass the 'path' argument to Base in the initializer list or create a
// default constructor for Base (which, of course, leaves Base::_t
// uninitialized).
class DerivedTwo : public virtual DerivedOne
{
public:
    DerivedTwo(const std::string& path) : DerivedOne(path) {}
    // This works
    // DerivedTwo(const std::string& path) : DerivedOne(path), Base(path) {} 
    virtual ~DerivedTwo() {}
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
test.cc: In constructor ‘DerivedTwo::DerivedTwo(const string&)’:
test.cc:31:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::Base()’
     DerivedTwo(const std::string& path) : DerivedOne(path) {}
                                                          ^
test.cc:7:5: note: candidate: Base<T>::Base(const T&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
     Base(const T& t) : _t(t) {}
     ^
test.cc:7:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cc:5:7: note: candidate: Base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::Base(const Base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)
 class Base {
       ^
test.cc:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Why do I need to declare a default constructor when it seems that the parameterized constructor should be called? Why must I explicitly pass DerivedTwo's parameter to Base, since I've passed it to DerivedOne (who should pass it to Base)?

Is there some way to avoid this duplication? Does this mean I can't use initializer lists when a base template constructor parameter is allocated on the heap in a derived class initializer list?

Comment: This is how virtual inheritance works.  Did you mean to actually use `virtual` in `class DerivedOne : public virtual Base<std::string>` and `class DerivedTwo : public virtual DerivedOne`?   Do note that it is not needed to use virtual functions.

Comment: In the real word application, there is a need for virtual functions. I still don't see why it is necessary, maybe I need to brush up on virtual inheritance.

Comment: Virtual inheritance is only needed when you inherit common ancestor more than once through multiple inheritance.

Comment: I can understand that DerivedTwo calls the Base class's constructor directly, but why isn't the constructor argument deduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What is going on

When you inherit virtually, you are asking that the type you inherit from is a "singleton" within the object heiarchy (not a program-wide singleton, but a instance-wide singleton, strange as that may seem).

As a side effect, the *actual most derived class* is responsible for constructing the virtual base class, regardless of what intermediate classes exist.

Virtual inheritance is intended when you need to inherit from some class more than once, yet ensure that only one instance exists.  Rather than work out some complex set of rules to determine whose constructor call would be the one to be called, the designers of C++ mandated that the most-derived class (the actual one being created) dictates exactly what constructor is called.

Everyone else can chime in, but only if an actual instance of *that* specific class (and not a more-derived one) is created does their opinion matter.

## You probably don't want `virtual` there

`virtual` inheritance has almost nothing to do with `virtual` methods/member functions.  Don't use it unless you need to for binary layout or diamond inheritance reasons.

Simply eliminate it from your code, and if you never inherit from a class along 2 different paths to the same most-derived class, you won't miss it.

```
class DerivedOne : public Base<std::string>
```

and

```
class DerivedTwo : public DerivedOne
```

and your code compiles and does what you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was starting to get pretty frustrated. This clears up an glaring misunderstanding my use of virtual inheritance!

Comment: @vincent, yes, the use of the same keyword here is rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

When you use *virtual inheritance* it is always the MOST DERIVED class that initializes the virtual base.  Even though your intermediate class passes a value up, it won't do that in further derived classes, which must directly initialize Base.

Since your most derived class (DerivedTwo) doesn't directly initialize Base, then Base is initialized without any parameters passed to it, and so requires a default constructor.

```
class DerivedTwo : public virtual DerivedOne
{
public:
    DerivedTwo(const std::string& path) : Base(path), DerivedOne(path) {}
}
```

Alternately, stop using virtual inheritance, and just use "normal" inheritance. That is, change this:

```
class DerivedOne : public virtual Base<std::string>
```

to this:

```
class DerivedOne : public Base<std::string>
```

Unless, of course, you really need virtual inheritance.  :)